# tar is too sticky for me at 70 yrs

Tags: tar

I need to install old firefox 57 so I can use my listen on repeat app. Won't work in quantum firefox. Trouble is I have NEVER understood how to extract tar files. Instructions from any site just don't ring my bell. Any suggestions. I'm using ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It might perhaps be better to describe what doesn't work exactly. Downgrading to an older version of Firefox is very ill advised, as there are security fixes which you will never get with the old version. If the web site you need requires Flash or Java, it might be best to find a new site or app to use, or to ask them to migrate into the modern age, by replacing the need for such plug-ins.

Comment: "old firefox 57" is also "quantum firefox".

Answer (score 0):

The tar command for an old firefox would look something like **tar -vxf** . Expand the older version of firefox into some directory within your id (NOT anything under /usr). Copy all scripts from the current firefox directory into your replacement firefox directory (there are either one or two). After setting aside the current firefox , which is at /usr/lib/firefox move in your older version but, before you do, 
things under /usr/lib should be root owned and grouped prior to setting in place.

Use **chgrp -R root** *firefox*   and **chown -R root** *firefox*  to set the right permissions before moving the old firefox in place.  These last two examples assume you are in your personal area where the older firefox was 'tarred to'.

This answer could be taken as a guide, it is not a cookbook solution.